# node.js (socket.io) stop comunicate with client after *catch* the error

Tags: node.js, error-handling, socket.io

With this code where deliberately I create some error, why nodejs/socket.io stop respond to the client? Note that nodejs process still up and nothing crash nor exit.

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    var d = domain.create();

    d.on('error', function(err) {
        socket.emit('error', err.message);
    });

    d.run(function() {
        execError();
    }
});
```

Comment: I can reproduce it, it seems to be a bug but I haven't looked into it very closely (yet).

Comment: update: I can receive data, but not send.

Comment: update 3:

If the error exists in the root of d.run() socket.io stop responding and after a while he reconnects.
But, if the error happens inside the same d.run() but inside the scope of something like: redclient.hget('hkey','key', d.bind(function (err, block) { ERROR(); }); socket.io caught the error and stay responding as nothing happen.

Comment: Very strange and quite unexpected behaviour, I think. Perhaps you should post a bug report on https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/issues

Answer (score 0):

Everything ok, was my code that create the issue.

More here about domains:

http://blog.evantahler.com/blog/on-domains-and-connections-with-node-js.html

https://gist.github.com/evantahler/4274698

Comment: UPDATE PART 2: nop not ok, is some listeners socket.on(...) the error is caught and socket.io stay ok and make all emits, but in others socket.io stop responding. :(